# Change AWS RDS Tier In Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

We needed to change the DB tier, but when doing it via the EB console it gave an odd error message...

```
Updating RDS database named: ******** failed Reason: Cannot upgrade mysql from 5.6.22 to 5.5.41
```

However, I managed successfully to change the DB tier via the RDS console instead.

The problem is, is that the EB console still shows the *old* DB tier, whilst RDS now shows it on the new one!

It has upgraded, but how do I get the EB console to show the correct information?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can only specify the DB version on environment launch in elastic beanstalk. You may do this via the console or using the DBEngineVersion [option setting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html). You cannot update it on an existing environment.

Since you changed the value out-of-band on the RDS directly, Elastic Beanstalk still thinks that the value hasn't changed. Hence it will continue to show you the old version. Your environment should continue to function correctly though. Let me know if you are facing any issues.

One caveat with making the change out-of-band is that if you save the environment configuration, clone or rebuild the environment you will get the old database version again on the new environment. So your change is not persisted across these operations.